# Add attributes to links with conditions

Tags: jquery

I am trying to determine outgoing links and add the target=”_blank” to them. However I want to add a filter and exclude some external links, how do I do?

For eg: Let’s say my domain is mydomain.com and I want all external hyperlinks going from it to have the target=_blank **except for** Microsoft.com, Google.com, Wikipedia.com etc. How do I exclude these url's from.

This is what I have written so far

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').attr('target','_blank');
```

Comment: `$('a[href^="http://"]:not([href*="google.com"]):not([href*="microsoft.com"]):not([href*="wikipedia.org"])')` for a _really_ primitive search

Comment: did u try specify your domain in filter, like $('a[href^="http://mydomain.com"]').attr('target','_blank'); ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `filter()` to do that.

This is really verbose to make a point, but you can use a ternary, regex or whatever you'd like to check the href against almost anything :

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    var ret = false;
    if ( this.href.indexOf('http://') === 0 ) { // everything that starts with http://
        if ( this.href.indexOf('http://google.com') === 0 ) { // starts with ...
           ret = true;
        }
        // or if
        if ( this.href.indexOf('microsoft.com') != -1 ) { // href contains microsoft.com
           ret = true;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}).attr('target','_blank');
```

with a regex:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    var rgx = new RegExp('/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:[^\.]+\.)?(microsoft\.com|google\.com|yahoo\.com)$/','gi');
    return this.href.match(rgx);
}).attr('target','_blank');
```

Comment: Sir this looks very good only if you would spare some time and explain the regex, that would simply be awesome. Thanks so much

Comment: Another issue is what if the external link already has a target=_blank. How do I check for it to avoid adding the same attribute to the link twice!

Comment: I just wrote the regex really fast based on another URL matching regex, but it should match http / https, subdomains, like www etc. and then the middle part should match the three domains seperated by the bitwise OR (`|`), It could be that you would have to edit that regex to make it match whatever it is you're trying to match. Adding the same attribute twice is not an issue, as jQuery doesn't add an attribute that is already there, in that case it only changes the current attribute.